# Are topological spaces (and open maps) comonadic over sets (and functions)?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, filters, monads

In the neighborhood formulation of topological spaces, the data of a topological space is a pair $(X,N)$ of a set $X$ and a function $N : X \to F X$, where $FX$ denotes the set of filters of subsets of $X$. We think of $N(x)$ as the filter of neighborhoods of the point $x \in X$. We can extend to an endofunctor $F: \mathbf{Set} \to  \mathbf{Set}$ by setting, for any function $f: X \to Y$, a function $Ff: FX \to FY$, given by $$Ff(\phi) : = \{A \subseteq Y ~|~ f^{-1}( A) \in \phi\}~~~~.$$

A topological space is then a coalgebra for this endofunctor, subject to some further axioms.

Furthermore, in the neighborhood formulation, a function $f: X \to Y$ is continuous between topological spaces $(X, N_X)$ and $(Y, N_Y)$ if, for any $x \in X$ and $A \in N_Y(f(x))$, $f^{-1}(A) \in N_X(x)$. In our terms, this is simply $N_Y \circ f \leq Ff \circ N_X$. A continuous function $f: (X, N_X) \to (X, N_Y)$ is open if, for any $x \in X$ and $A \in N_X(x)$, there exists $B\in N_Y(f (x))$ such that $B \subseteq f (A)$. After some reflection, this turns out to be equivalent to $Ff \circ N_X \leq N_Y \circ f $. Thus a function is continuous and open if $N_Y \circ f = Ff \circ N_X$, i.e. if it is a coalgebra homomorphism.

It would be nice if this could be refined so as to recover the category of topological spaces and open maps as a category of coalgebras for a comonad. It looks like $F$ is not actually a comonad as defined, so we would need another version of $F$ to get off the ground. Does anyone have ideas, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Actually it is conservative on the open continuous maps -- an open continuous bijection is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Nevermind. I shouldn’t post while being tired. Great question btw.

Comment: Probably related? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265596/topology-from-the-viewpoint-of-the-filter-endofunctor Also, see [Barr's theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relational+beta-module), although it is about monads; it seems to me that your computation proves that lax coalgebras are continuous functions, and strict coalgebras are continuous _and open_ maps.

Comment: Thanks, definitely a related question. The computation shows that continuous maps are lax morphisms of coalgebras for an endofunctor, subject to some axioms. My hope was that those axioms could be understood as instances of the axioms of coalgebras for a comonad in some fashion.

Comment: Can you send a link or spell out exactly what are the further axioms for a topological space in the coalgebra setting?

Comment: The neighborhood axioms are: every neighborhood for each point $x \in X$ indeed contains $x$, and
    each neighborhood  $A \in N(x)$ contains some $B\in N(x)$ such that for each $y \in B$, $A \in N(y)$.